# Creating new table from columns in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In full disclosure, I was kind of thrown into a project this week using SQL and, unfortunately, have very little experience using it up until now outside of very basic querying. I'm going to start studying up, but really could use some help here in the short-term.

In this example, the tables are named `Person_PR` and `Person_CME`.

Both tables

- contain information pertaining to the same person and contain the same person identifiers(record_num and person_num).
- are sorted by record_num and person_num, so they are in total alignment.

Tables:

Person_PR

```
record_num, person_num, pr_variable1, pr_variable2
```

Person_CME

```
record_num, person_num, cme_variable1, cme_varable2
```

I'd like for the new table `Person_new` to contain `record_num, person_num, cme_variable1, cme_varable2, pr_variable1 and pr_variable2`.

- The `cme_` variables would come from the `Person_CME` table and
- the `pr_` variables would come from the `Person_PR` table.

New table `Person_new`:

```
record_num, person_num, cme_variable1, cme_varable2, pr_variable1, pr_variable2
```

I have attempted to do this using both insert into and create table as select methods, but am unable to get anything to work properly. I was hoping that someone could get me started in the right direction. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this and any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate data in a database?

Comment: How large are these tables?

Comment: You should avoid creating a copy of your data with the columns you want. You should instead create a query that contains the data you want. Also, tables do not have an order. The only way to order data is to put an order by clause on your select statement.

Comment: @Dai Well, I'm needing to create an access form that calls upon data from both tables. I know that I can use subforms in Access to call on multiple tables, but for layout purposes, it will look a lot better if I can somehow combine the variables of interest into one table and then have just one Access form calling on that table.

Comment: So in fact you want a stored procedure that uses the select statement as Sean Lange suggested.  You can then populate your form from the results of that stored procedure.

Comment: Again...you don't do this by creating copies of your data. Think about how hard it will be when you have 40 forms and they each have a copy of the data. How do you handle updating your data? This is why we query the data when we need it for the front end. Create a view if you need to but don't copy data like you are describing.

Comment: @photec Do you want a) to edit the data in your access form and updated it back to the database or is it b) readonly?
b) meaning you would like to display the data but not update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to create a new table in sql server is

```
SELECT p.record_num
     , p.person_num
     , c.cme_variable1
     , c.cme_variable2
     , p.pr_variable1
     , p.pr_variable2
INTO new_table
FROM Person_PR p
INNER JOIN Person_CME c 
   ON  p.person_num = c.person_num
   AND p.record_num = b.record_num
```

However, it may make more sense to use a view to present the data you want.

Comment: Thanks FJT and everyone else that contributed. This is exactly what I was looking for. I should have added that I wanted to do data entry into the table being created, rather than just call it/view it like I made it sound. Thanks again, this will be a tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a stored procedure, not a new table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].GetPersonData

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  cme.record_num ,
            cme.person_num ,
            cme.cme_variable1 ,
            cme.cme_variable2 ,
            pr.prvariable1 ,
            pr.prvariable2
    FROM    Person_CME cme
            INNER JOIN Person_PR pr ON cme.record_num = pr.record_num
                                       AND cme.person_num = pr.person_num

END
```

You can then use the stored procedure as the record source for your Access form.  There is no need to create a new table, which would need to be periodically refreshed and would stored duplicate data.  You could also you a view if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, Object Explorer, you can right click the table, Script Table As, Create To, New Query Editor Window. Create a 3rd query window, copy and paste the fields you want to take from each table, and execute the script to create the new table.

You can also do it with a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT record_num, person_num, cme_variable1, cme_varable2, pr_variable1, and pr_variable2
INTO Person_new
FROM Person_PR
JOIN Person_CME ON 1=2
```

From there you can edit through Object Explorer.

If you want to include the DATA from both tables, make it a view rather than trying to maintain a seperate table:

```
CREATE VIEW Person_new AS
SELECT PR.record_num, person_num, cme_variable1, cme_varable2, pr_variable1, and pr_variable2
FROM Person_PR AS PR
JOIN Person_CME AS CME ON PR.record_num = CME.record_num AND PR.person_num = CME.person_num
```

You enforce order by including an ORDER BY clause in any select statements, tables are not "ordered"